# A word to describe type of question (questioning the future)

Tags: questions

I know what a rhetorical question is. But this is more like me asking a question which will definitely draw an assumption or a guess as an answer.

For example : What do you think the oil prices would be in 5 years time?

Can i describe this type of question in one word?

Comment: It's a "question" -- straight and simple. Unrelated to rhetoricality.

Comment: A *guessable question* ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for [***speculative***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speculative):

> based on guesses or ideas about what might happen or be true
>   rather than on facts   – MW